# PJSip in android

Tags: android, pjsip

I'm trying to build a `Sip client` for android using `pjsip`such as [`CSipSimple`](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) project. However, i actually don't know much about `pjsip`. Does anyone have a tutorial about pjsip or something like that to build a `Sip softphone` in android using PJsip lib?
 Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: Is there a tutoprial. Sadly I can't use the native SIP API. Any suggestions where to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to use third-party libraries to build SIP client functionality in Android. Android includes a full fledged [SIP API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html). You can take a look at [SIP demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html) to understand how to use SIP APIs for a walkie-talkie type of implementation.

Comment: Note that this will limit your application to Android version 2.3 [(API Level 9)](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html#level9) and higher, but I guess that is something like 75% of the user base

Comment: According to Play Store statistics on [Platform Versions](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html), your guess is right (as on the day of this comment)

Comment: this also limit your app to wi-fi only, which is not usefull.... do you know any other way to use pjsip except apjsua because apjsua is not working , i have spent days on it.....

Comment: I have heard good comments about [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/). You may check it out.

Comment: I have build CSipSimple successfully, but it is very challenging to change UI and make it work according to you and also there may be some legal issues while using their code. That's why I wanted a basic demo like apjsua which is provided by pjsip, but it is giving me error while registration. If you have worked on pjsip then it will be a great help for me.

Comment: Please post the issues faced by you as a new question and someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @Rajesh The link to SIP demo is not available anymore, please update the new link

Comment: @entropy, the samples are no longer available on the developer site, they have to be downloaded using the SDK Manager.

Comment: @Rajesh i'm using Android Studio SDK Manager doesn't show any option to download samples!

Comment: The post and the comments above are quite old. In fact, there was no Android Studio at the time of writing it. You can find the samples by doing a [web search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=SIP+demo).

Comment: Define "full fledged". The provided SIP API is lacking in many respects, most notably for me: the ability to make any custom modifications to the audio stream and inability to fine tune SIP parameters by hand.

Comment: @Rajesh, I implemented full-fledged SIP API as per your suggestion, peer to peer SIP audio call is working fine, but not able to listen voice from both sides. I thought it's because of ICE and TURN server enable. How can I enable ICE and TURN server.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer isn't entirely accurate. There are many desirable features missing from the Android SIP API that you may wish to achieve via a 3rd-party library.

With respect to the aforementioned pjsip, I've spent a great deal of time experimenting with the Android build of pjsip, and truthfully the only way to get reliable instantaneous registration to work as documented is to build the OpenSSL 1.0.2a library and pass it at configure time. Then in Java you need to attempt (and fail) to enable TLS communication, just as you see them do for UDP and TCP. Here is what I mean:

```
  /* Create transports. */
  try { transports.add( ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS, transportConfig) ); }
  catch (Throwable t2) { SipManager.log().e(t2); }

  try { transports.add( ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, transportConfig) ); }
  catch (Throwable t) { SipManager.log().e(t); }

  try { transports.add( ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TCP, transportConfig) ); }
  catch (Throwable t) { SipManager.log().e(t); }
```

Replace the `SipManager.log()` calls for your own app.

I'm not entirely sure why, but this is necessary for me. Otherwise, the registration process is semi-nondeterministic, in the sense that it will work after failing a few times, or fail for 5 minutes then suddenly succeed, etc. It seems to get confused after the 1st registration.

Here is how I configured:

```
TARGET_ABI=arm64-v8a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags --with-ssl=`pwd`/../3rd-party/openssl-1.0.2a
```

And that was after following the [proper Android instructions](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android), exrtacting the OpenSSL tarball into a folder above pjsip `../3rd-party/` and first building there. I described that process in some detail in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045742/60-120fps-preview-data-on-an-android-device/37215183#37215183).

Answer (score 1):

### i wouldnt recomment Android default sip stack to build a softphone. I have made a same mistake and had lots  of issue. some of disadvantages i came across using android default sip stack

1. it doesnt support Dtmf tone
2. - it doesnt support video call
3. -it support quite a limited version of android and it would not going to support older version android, specially those non standard
   android version available on those cheap tablets.

So after wasting about a month , i have developmed entire app again using pjsip. It wasnt as easy as android sip stack   ,but worth its feature

Answer (score 0):

i wouldnt  use Android buildin  Sipstack Api as a first option.It lacks lots of basic call functionality and doesnt support on lots of  Android devices.
I would rather suggest PJSip for production.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to develop only sip client then you can use android's sip API but as mentioned in above answers it will limit your apps features.
But if you want to develop chat or calling facilities in your app then you can use pjsip which provides many rich features.
As for building pjsip for android, you can learn from [here(android)](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) and for ios,learn from [here(ios)](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone).
Basically, pjsip gives you many APIs with rich features which you can use as per your requirements like pjlib, pjsip, PJ media, pjsua etc. pjsua (or pjsua2 for android) are higher level API which helps you to extract maximum output with minimum complexities.you can see directly [here.](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/1537216238d1de04428bdcda2ea6ff6f05cc63e6/687474703a2f2f7777772e706a7369702e6f72672f646f63732f6c61746573742f706a7369702f646f63732f68746d6c2f706a7369702d617263682e6a7067)you can learn about pjsua from [here](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/latest/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB.htm). They have also provided a demo app [(pjsua CLI)](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/PJSUA-CLI) , [Pjsua CLI](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsua.htm) and its source which will help you to understand the basic structure of an app to build with pjsip having chat and calling functions.

for Android, you can see a demo application at [github](https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android).