# camera2 API frames skip and crash when >= 65[FPS]

Tags: android, crash, frame-rate, android-camera2, mediarecorder

I'm currently developing an Android App for slow-motion recording using [this project](https://github.com/mobapptuts/android_camera2_api_video_app) as an example. I've tried this App with a ZTE BLADE L5 PLUS (Android 5.0) and it worked just fine, but since I need more than 30[FPS] to get a quality slow-motion video, I've changed to a Sony Xperia XZs (Android 8.0) and tried this App.

I have 2 problems now:

**1.-Frames skipped:**
When I record from 30 (haven't tried less) to 65 FPS, the app looses ocasionally more frames than the ones I fixed with mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(int) which actually makes the video output to "freeze" for more than 1 second. Why does this happen and how to prevent it?

**2.-If I set a value >= 65 FPS the app just crashes:**
I don't actually know what I'm doing wrong in here. If someone sees something in the code that could make it fail, I'll appreciate all the help.

**CODE:**

```
    private void setupMediaRecorder() throws IOException
{
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(mTotalRotation);
    try
    {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**LOG WITH < 65FPS:**

```
    11-07 11:33:28.788 9285-9309/com.company.www.project I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8996.so from the current namespace instead.
11-07 11:33:28.793 9285-9309/com.company.www.project I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff087, ME: 0x005ff063
11-07 11:33:28.809 9285-9309/com.company.www.project I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-07 11:33:28.846 9285-9285/com.company.www.project I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
11-07 11:33:28.874 9285-9285/com.company.www.project E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.camera.cfa.packagelist"
11-07 11:33:28.862 9285-9285/com.company.www.project W/.project: type=1400 audit(0.0:1356): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:camera_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=3332 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:camera_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 ppid=1034 pcomm="main" pgid=1034 pgcomm="main"
11-07 11:33:28.874 9285-9285/com.company.www.project E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.camera.cfa.packagelist"
11-07 11:33:28.879 9285-9290/com.company.www.project I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=27KB, data=23KB
    After code cache collection, code=27KB, data=23KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
11-07 11:33:28.936 9285-9309/com.company.www.project I/vndksupport: sphal namespace is not configured for this process. Loading /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8996.so from the current namespace instead.
11-07 11:33:31.638 9285-9290/com.company.www.project I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=50KB, data=44KB
    After code cache collection, code=50KB, data=44KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
11-07 11:33:31.639 9285-9290/com.company.www.project I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
11-07 11:33:39.400 9285-9290/com.company.www.project I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=90KB
11-07 11:33:39.401 9285-9290/com.company.www.project I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=89KB, data=59KB
11-07 11:34:00.273 9285-9285/com.company.www.project I/Choreographer: Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-07 11:34:00.729 9285-9290/com.company.www.project I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=124KB, data=82KB
    After code cache collection, code=124KB, data=82KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
11-07 11:34:21.830 9285-9285/com.company.www.project I/Choreographer: Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

**LOG >= 65FPS:**

```
11-07 12:14:59.806 10366-10366/com.company.www.project E/MediaRecorder: prepare failed: -2147483648
11-07 12:14:59.806 10366-10366/com.company.www.project W/System.err: java.io.IOException: prepare failed.
11-07 12:14:59.807 10366-10366/com.company.www.project W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaRecorder._prepare(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.prepare(MediaRecorder.java:954)
        at com.company.www.project.MainActivity.setupMediaRecorder(MainActivity.java:444)
        at com.company.www.project.MainActivity.startRecord(MainActivity.java:456)
        at com.company.www.project.MainActivity.checkWriteStoragePermission(MainActivity.java:412)
        at com.company.www.project.MainActivity.access$800(MainActivity.java:42)
        at com.company.www.project.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:191)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24710)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6572)
11-07 12:14:59.808 10366-10366/com.company.www.project W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
11-07 12:14:59.808 10366-10366/com.company.www.project E/MediaRecorder: SurfaceMediaSource could not be initialized!
11-07 12:14:59.810 10366-10366/com.company.www.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.company.www.project, PID: 10366
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to get surface
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.getSurface(Native Method)
        at com.company.www.project.MainActivity.startRecord(MainActivity.java:467)
        at com.company.www.project.MainActivity.checkWriteStoragePermission(MainActivity.java:412)
        at com.company.www.project.MainActivity.access$800(MainActivity.java:42)
        at com.company.www.project.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:191)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24710)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6572)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Thanks for your time =)

Comment: don't you rather need the [setCaptureRate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setCaptureRate(double)) here?

Comment: Yeah it might be needed when I actually implement the slow-motion, but at this moment I'm just trying it to run at normal speed (first I want the camera to actually work, and then i'll implement the slow-motion part)

Comment: Cameras don't necessarily support arbitrary frame rate, and even for supported rate, the official docs say that `setVideoFrameRate()` may not be met exactly, e.g. due to lighting conditions.

Comment: Yes, I've already know that after watching it in an answer in stackoverflow, but I need it workinging w/ 120 FPS. I also know that not all videos will have 30FPS if I for example setVideoFrameRate(30) but the video will have a value around that (wich for my app is good enough). The real problem in here is the fact of skipping frames, the crash with > say 60FPS and that E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.camera.cfa.packagelist" error wich I don't know if it has something to do and if it has a solution.

Comment: If the camera is LEGACY level, you should better avoid camera2 API

Comment: I'm using an app called "Camera2 probe" for checkingthe hardware level support of my Sony Xperia XZs and it says Full level. I've also checked Sony and they say it has full support except for taking RAW images. Anyway, do u have any other idea than using camera2 API for slow motion recording? If you do, I will much appreciate your help =).
Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

OK I've found a partial answer which I'm sharing with the next problem I encountered :)
So what I did now was taking the QUALITY_HIGH profile as a base for my mMediaRecorder and just changed the bitRate and FrameRate trying it to record at 120 FPS just like this:

```
private void setupMediaRecorder() throws IOException
{
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(profile.fileFormat);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(8000000);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(120);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);

    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);

    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(mTotalRotation);
    try
    {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I'm recording videos of 30FPS wich I don't actually understand--> How can it be if I'm setting 120FPS on the MediaRecorder?

Any idea on how to get a the MediaRecorder to actually record at 120FPS?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need [QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_HIGH](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#QUALITY_HIGH_SPEED_HIGH) or some other profile. Unfortunately, there is no documented way (which means, reliably works different devices from different manufacturers) to check which profiles are actually supported.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I've checked in my device with hasProfile() method and unfortunately the device only has QUALITY_HIGH and QUALITY_LOW =,(. But on friday, before leaving work I've seen something related with creating a constrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession. Do you know something about this?

Comment: sorry, no first-hand experience with constrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession

Comment: Well thanks for your help anyway. I'm working on it trying to understand how it really works (it seems Sony devices even though have great cameras put some problems to developers). If I get to a solution I'll try to post it in here in some way.

Comment: For those interested in this thread, it seems that Sony's high speed mode is capped for developers so you can only record at 30FPS at most. I'm currently trying to flash my ROM to an AOSP wishing that it let's me use high speed FPS ranges that the camera actually has. I'm using this guide for that: https://developer.sony.com/develop/open-devices/guides/aosp-build-instructions/build-aosp-oreo-8-0-kernel-4-4#tutorial-step-5

Comment: Check my answer for implementation of constrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following configuration to record at 30, 60, 90 and 120 fps.

Source:
`$ git clone https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/camera-samples -b iot-concam-apk.lnx.1.1`

```
    private var streamConfigOpMode: Int = 0x00
    private val HIGH_SPEED_SESSION: Int = 1
```

```
        previewRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE, Range(previewFps, previewFps))
        if (previewFps == 120) streamConfigOpMode = streamConfigOpMode or HIGH_SPEED_SESSION

        Log.d(TAG, "Operation Mode: $streamConfigOpMode")
        val config = SessionConfiguration(
                streamConfigOpMode, outConfigurations, HandlerExecutor(cameraHandler),
                object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    override fun onConfigured(s: CameraCaptureSession) {

                        if (previewFps == 120) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onConfigured HFR session")
                            sessionHFR = s as CameraConstrainedHighSpeedCaptureSession
                            // if there is no active surface, do not set setRepeatingBurst.
                            if (streamSurfaceList.isNotEmpty()) {
                                var requestList = sessionHFR.createHighSpeedRequestList(previewRequest.build())
                                sessionHFR.setRepeatingBurst(requestList, null, cameraHandler)
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onConfigured session")
                            session = s
                            // if there is no active surface, do not set setRepeatingRequest.
                            if (streamSurfaceList.isNotEmpty()) {
                                if ((streamSurfaceList.size == 2) && (previewFps == 60 || previewFps == 90)) {
                                    optimizePreviewFPS(previewFps)
                                } else {
                                    session.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest.build(), null, cameraHandler)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        isCameraReady = true
                        Log.i(TAG, "isCameraReady true")
                    }

                    override fun onConfigureFailed(s: CameraCaptureSession) =
                            s.device.close()
                })

        config.sessionParameters = previewRequest.build()
        camera.createCaptureSession(config)
        Log.i(TAG, "createSession exit")
```

```
    private fun optimizePreviewFPS(previewFps: Int) {
        when (previewFps) {
            60 -> {
                var burstList = mutableListOf<CaptureRequest>()
                burstList.add(previewRequest.build())
                // First Surface is always display.
                previewRequest.removeTarget(streamSurfaceList[0])
                burstList.add(previewRequest.build())
                session.setRepeatingBurst(burstList, null, cameraHandler)
                previewRequest.addTarget(streamSurfaceList[0])
            }
            90 -> {
                var burstList = mutableListOf<CaptureRequest>()
                burstList.add(previewRequest.build())
                // First Surface is always display.
                previewRequest.removeTarget(streamSurfaceList[0])
                burstList.add(previewRequest.build())
                burstList.add(previewRequest.build())
                session.setRepeatingBurst(burstList, null, cameraHandler)
                previewRequest.addTarget(streamSurfaceList[0])
            }
        }
    }
```